# PHP, Enter the form infrmation in the url

Tags: php, html, url, passwords

How can I input form data via the url in php .
well i want to write an App that has a login. Well i rather make a mysql DB, then the andrioid DB. So i wanted them to input the login information and then pass value it to the login.php. So i was hoping i could do it in the url. 
I have Form that asks for username and password.
Then it logs you. 
I want to be able to put the information in a url. I thought that this would work
so like `www/localhost/login.php?myusername=john&mypassword=1234`
but this doesn't work. Any idea if this can be done?

Comment: If your form uses `GET`, this will happen automatically. However, it is strongly recommended to use `POST` to send login credentials and then you will not see anything in the url. Some example reasons not to use `GET`: Anybody can see it, the complete urls will be stored in log files, browser history, etc.

Comment: in the html form you use, you have to set the Method="Get". dont use it for login forms

Comment: *"www/localhost/login.php?myusername=john&mypassword=1234"* - You're asking for trouble doing this.

Comment: *"for some reason this doesn't work. Any idea if this can be done?"* - Post your code.

Comment: I'm starting to think you're a troll.

Comment: not a troll just don't know much about php. Sorry if i seem so dumb that i must be joking with people. Back to the GET METHOD. So if i use GET instead of Post, i can enter the user info in the url?

Comment: Well, you haven't accepted any answers yet; some of which are from me and are working examples that I've tested. I don't post busted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put information in URL, you must use "GET" method. Not "POST"

If this is not what you want, please explain your problem.

BTW. I don't suggest you to do important proccesses like logging in with GET. Keep that in mind.

Comment: So if i change my form from Post , to GET. i can input the username and password in the url, like www/localhost/login.php?myusername=john&mypassword=1234 ?

Comment: Yes. Why didn't you try?

Answer (score 2):

Its unclear what you are trying to ask, but I will try to clear your doubt.

as per your question your basic html should look like

```
<form action="log.php" method="get">
 Username:<input type="text"name="username">
 Password:<input type="password"name="password">
 <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

and in **log.php** you can access submitted values like

```
<?php
$username=$_GET['username'];
$password=$_GET['password'];
echo "Username:".$username."<br>";
echo "Password:".$password."<br>";
?>
```

But its highly recommended to use **POST** instead of **GET** while sending sensitive data such as passwords and switching is really simple.
in form you need to define method to post like.

```
<form action="log.php" method="post">
```

and in *PHP* use `$_POST` instead.
Hope It helps.

Comment: well i want to write an App that has a login. Well i rather make a mysql DB, then the andrioid DB. So i wanted them to input the login information and then pass value it to the login.php. So i was hoping i could do it in the url.